# using wildcards to copy directories in .bat files

Tags: batch-file

I have created a .bat file where i input a job number. I want to copy the contents of one folder using the input value with wildcards to another with only the input value. It will not copy the contents of this folder using wildcards. Any suggestions?

sample:

```
Input = 19000

c:\test2\19000 project\test.doc
c:\test\19000
```

.bat file below

```
COLOR 0a
:USERID
CLS
ECHO Enter User Name:
ECHO > NUL
SET /p USERID=
IF %USERID% EQU c GOTO PASSWORD
IF %USERID% LSS  c GOTO INVALID
IF %USERID% GTR  c GOTO INVALID
:PASSWORD
CLS
ECHO Enter Password:
SET /p PASSWORD=
IF %PASSWORD% EQU c GOTO :job number
IF %PASSWORD% LSS c GOTO INVALID
IF %PASSWORD% GTR c GOTO INVALID
CLS
:INVALID
ECHO INAVLID LOGIN.....
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > NUL
ECHO Please try again...
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > NUL
GOTO USERID
:Job Number
Set input1=
set /p input1= Job Number: 
cls
ECHO OFF
c:
cd\
xcopy "c:\test2\%input1% "*" " "c:\test\%input1%" /e
cd\
c:
cls
EOF
exit
```

Comment: The space in your `xcopy` line seems like it would try to copy `%input1%` into everything, no?

Comment: i created a directory called 19000. i then renamed the source directory to add more words. I am trying to address the directory after the fact using a wild card. but it will not recognize the "*".

Comment: John already told you-the space between the first pathname and the wildcard is why it's not working. Remove the space and quotes around the wildcard.

Comment: xcopy "c:\test2\%input1%*" "c:\test\%input1%" /e

Comment: this created the new directory in 19000 called "19000 projects". But it did not copy the files that were in the source directory. Thanks for your patience and help. Yes i am a newbie!!!

Comment: when i reality i did not want the directory created in the second folder. I only wanted to copy the sub folders and files from the first folder to the input folder 19000 in the second folder

Comment: Try adding a better description of the exact task to your question.  Explain the folder structure and what you need to do.

Comment: input = 19000   first directory is called "test2\19000 project". second directory is called test\19000. i want to xcopy files and sub directories from one folder to the other. the command i am using is xcopy "c:\test2\%input%*" "c:\test\%input" /e. It is creating a folder in the second directory, but it is not copying any files or sub directories over.

Answer (score 0):

This should xcopy any folder that matches the query with a wildcard after it, to the `c:\test\` folder with the same folder structure.

```
@echo off
COLOR 0a
CLS
:USERID
SET /p "USERID=Enter User Name: "
IF "%USERID%" NEQ "c" GOTO INVALID
ECHO(
SET /p "PASSWORD=Enter Password: "
IF "%PASSWORD%" NEQ "c" GOTO INVALID
ECHO(
Set "input1="
set /p "input1=Job Number: " 
for /d /r "c:\test2\" %%a in ("%input1%*") do (
xcopy "%%a\*.*" "c:\test\%%~nxa\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
)
cls
exit
goto :EOF

:INVALID
ECHO INVALID LOGIN.....
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > NUL
ECHO Please try again...
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > NUL
goto :userid
```

Comment: OMG foxidrive......i changed a few few of the variables and it worked perfectly!!!!!  Many thanks!!!!!!!